# SurfaceView And Camera in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

people. I have a problem. I want to have Relative Layout in which to put FrameLayout( in it will be the camera View) and Surface View with transparent background over it. So I will draw something and the background will become from the camera view. But I have a problem - when the SurfaceView is created the draw method is called 2 times. So when I start to draw from another thread the result of the drawing from these first 2 times doesn't dispeared, so I have 2 pictures on the screen, but I want only 1. The idea is to move a picture from one place to another in screen and now I have this picture 2 times - in the initial position and at the current position. The only question is why the drawn things from the first 2 draws are not deleted?
[image]

```
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/cameraViewHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <com.example.gamecamerashooter.GameView
       android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shotButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/shoot"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

In the picture I upload I  don't want the left Android. The numbers are fps - the 0 is from beginning, 45 is currentFPS. This is my problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your draw routine begin by clearing the screen?  If not, you'll see artifacts from the double-buffering.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I try to use postInvalidate() in draw method and this works (I thing). But one of times when I tested it - it happens again(for a moment the previous surface wasn't deleted). I can use invalidate, but it is written to use invalidate only from UI Thread. So what is the best I can do? Or I can call invalidate with runOnUIThread ? And one more question - why super.draw(canvas) isn't working? I thought that this should clear the screen ? Maybe I don't have enough practice with surface view and I misunderstand something.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And why should I call both of super.draw(canvas) and postInvalidate() ? Why super.draw sometimes clear the surface and sometimes not(in the beginning)? Before use postInvalidate I have 44-45 frames for something super simple (why?) and now I have 31-32 frames . :(

Comment: And why if I use cavnas.drawColor(Black) after that only the things drawn in the first frame can be seen? Maybe it is, because of the mode, but why only the first is over the black and what is the mode that I can draw normal(when draw after that the drawn thing to appear above the black).
Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a lot about your questions that I'm not understanding.  You should be overriding `onDraw()`, not `draw()`; see http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html .  The View portion of a SurfaceView is usually transparent to let the Surface show through, so if you draw on the View you need to clear to transparent black (alpha=0).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I try to override onDraw and to use 

  Canvas c = getHolder().lockCanvas(null);
        synchronized (getHolder()) {
            onDraw(c);
        }

        getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

And eclipse shows - Suspicious method call; should probably call "draw" rather than "onDraw" and don't want to compile the project. Why is that.

Comment: You don't call onDraw().  You override it, and the framework calls it whenever it needs to redraw the View.  If you want to draw on the Surface, rather than the View, then you don't use draw() or onDraw() or anything else from the View hierarchy; you just draw whenever you feel like it.  Trivial example of drawing on a Surface here: https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/MultiSurfaceActivity.java (start in startBouncing()).  Note you can't draw on the Surface if you're sending your Camera preview there.

Comment: I saw this on this tutorial - http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame3.html . I watch this tutorial one month ago and I have doubt that maybe I am not sure when exactly to use SurfaceView. My idea is to make shooter game - there is a crosshair and you should kill zombies.